# How to Use DELETE and INSERT simultaneously in Query Script

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery(Uses Standard SQL) but I have a Table with some data. Based on the data in the Table, I want to insert fake messages rows to that table, and after that, delete all data(the newly inserted fake messages) from that table, But I do worry of deleting all of data within that table . Any examples of how to properly query something like this?

Comment: Can you insert the same guid into any of the columns in the table, then delete where x = that same guid? Many times i used that pattern: `declare @g uniqueidentifier = newid(); insert into table(col1, someguid) select col1, @g from table where x = y; delete from table where someguid = @g`

Comment: You want to add data to a table, and delete that new data at the same time? What's the desired effect?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Sorry I wasnt clear with my question but I want to insert fake messages  first then If i get my required result then delete these messages with a fake message identifier

Comment: @CaiusJard can I use this method for multiple tables?

Comment: Sure, with same or different guid. Note I used SQL Server syntax/function names to illustrate my point; it's not guaranteed to work by straight paste into BigQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about accidentally deleting data, I would create a view that combines your actual data with your fake data.

```
CREATE VIEW project.dataset.my_view
AS

select message from project.dataset.actual_table 
UNION ALL
select 'This is a fake message 1' as message
UNION ALL
select 'This is a fake message 2' as message
```

You can query against this view without changing underlying data, and when you are done, simply delete the view.  Much safer than playing around with important data if you aren't crystal clear on what you are doing.