# INSERT new Values into multiple Tables then DELETE these new inserted values(rows) based on specific identifier

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello Everyone I wanted to know if it is possible to Insert new values into multiple tables(in my case 22) in a single query. Once they are inserted I want to delete these 22(newly inserted rows) and move  the deleted rows into a separate table ?

Comment: what the point here? can you explain your real use case? the question is it is asked mow - makes no sense so hard to answer

Comment: its just for testing purposes in bigquery by adding some fake messages(data)

Comment: so no - you cannot insert using single query - check out scripting

Comment: Hmm is it possible to this with tables with different fields in scripting?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006270/how-to-use-delete-and-insert-simultaneously-in-query-script/60008519#60008519 .

Comment: what you mean by with different fields and if those are actually totally different tables - why you would even expect to do all in `a single query`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "a single query". You cannot do it in a single SQL statement like `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`. But you can create a single query with multiple SQL statements using BigQuery Scripting (currently in Beta).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

Note that these multiple updates are not transactional, BigQuery uses single-statement transactions.